# NE555-controlled transformer voltage spikes

Tags: transformer, 555, transient-suppression

I am attempting to build a NE555-timer-controlled step-up transformer (3:250). R2 and R3 will be variable resistors when it is completed. Input is 12 V and I'm stepping that up to about 1000 V.

The problem is I am getting these vicous voltage spikes caused by the rapidly collapsing magnetic field across L1 and consequently voltages way above 1000 V on L2. Is there a way to control this as I only want about 1000 V across R5?

[image]

[image: Revision 1 Schematic]

Answer (score 1):

You should try driving your transformer with a half-bridge followed by a capacitor.

[image]

- The left graph is the node between the two transistors.
- The middle graph is left "*out*".
- The right graph is the right "*out*".
- The CLK source is the output of your NE555 (the node of M1's gate in your schematic).

This way the drains of the half-bridge transistors will stay within sane voltages while the node between the capacitor and inductor are a little bit higher. And finally you get a 1 kV across your 4 MΩ resistor.

Here is the [link](http://www.falstad.com/circuit/circuitjs.html?cct=$%201%200.000005%201.3241202019156522%2030%205%2050%0Af%2080%20416%20128%20416%201%201.5%202%0Ar%20304%20448%20304%20544%200%204000000%0Ag%20304%20544%20304%20560%200%0Ag%20176%20544%20176%20560%200%0Aw%20256%20448%20304%20448%200%0AR%2080%20416%2048%20416%201%202%201186%202.5%202.5%200%200.5%0AR%20128%20400%20128%20368%200%200%2040%205%200%200%200.5%0Ac%20128%20448%20176%20448%200%200.00018%206.158481420470227%0Af%2080%20480%20128%20480%200%201.5%202%0Aw%20128%20448%20128%20464%200%0Ag%20128%20496%20128%20560%200%0Aw%2080%20416%2080%20480%200%0AT%20176%20448%20256%20544%200%200.00009999999999999999%2083%20-12.25000002466044%200.000013997553245258601%200.999%0Ag%20256%20544%20256%20560%200%0Aw%20128%20432%20128%20448%200%0AO%20176%20448%20176%20400%200%0AO%20256%20448%20256%20400%200%0Ao%209%201%200%204098%2010%2012.8%200%202%209%203%0Ao%2015%201%200%204098%2020%200.1%201%201%0Ao%2016%201%200%204098%202560%200.1%202%201%0A) to the simulation in case you want to play around.

---

In order to drive a LC tank, you have to match the resonating frequency of the LC tank.

This formula can be used to calculate the oscillating frequency in Hz if capacitance and inductance is known:

$$f=\frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{LC}}$$

This formula can be used to calculate the capacitance required if the frequency (in Hz) and inductance is known:

$$C=\frac{1}{L(2\pi f)^2}$$

Because you will be oscillating at the resonance frequency, magical things will happen. In an ideal world with ideal components, the voltage across \$R_5\$ would go into the 200 kV range. In the simulation that does not happen because the transistors can't source/sink enough current to make that happen. So in your case you might get lower/higher voltage than 1 kV, it really depends on the \$r_{d(on)}\$ of your transistors and the ESR of the capacitor and transformer.

If you are getting too high voltages across \$R_5\$, then you can decrease it by increasing the size of the capacitor, and recalculate the resonance frequency. And vice versa if you are getting too low voltage, just reduce the capacitance value and recalculate the resonance frequency. You can also reduce the voltage across \$R_5\$ by adding a small series resistance with the capacitor so less energy will be transferred through the transformer.

---

### Feedback regarding your schematic:

I am not sure why you are using a 100 Ω in series with your NE555. I'd throw that away. I'd also reduce R4 to something like 20 Ω.

Comment: the 100Ω filters the supply, so that the switching noise stays out,

Comment: that circuit does not give 50% with an NE555, only with CMOS types like UA555 and TLC555

Comment: @Jasen Hmm.. 100 Ω and 0 F ... that's an interesting filter. - Ahhh of course, silly me. I had CMOS in mind.

Comment: @Harry Svensson What mosfets do you recommend? In my spice simulation there is about 20amps of current going through the two mosfets and 225 watts of power.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You are missing a snubber diode on L1. Use a 1N5822 Schottky diode with the band facing the MOSFET. It will clamp the return spike from the MOSFET being switched off, which can damage the MOSFET over time.

Change R4 to 33 ohms or so, to increase the on-off time. You can also insert a fast 1N4148 diode across R4 so the positive OFF pulse from the 555 has no delay. It is important that the MOSFET shut OFF rapidly.

If you missed it you need a 470 uF capacitor across the 555 power and ground pins, or its oscillations will be noisy.

This should clean up the waveform a lot.

Comment: If you attach a snubber diode on \$L_1\$, then the current through \$L_1\$ will keep going in the same direction all the time. You will build up this massive current.. At some point you will saturate \$L_1\$ and it will act as a heater. It will act very poorly as a transformer.

Comment: @HarrySvensson. Snubber diodes are common, though RC + diode combinations work better. A great snubber is a custom fit job. OP has many design mistakes, like no bypass cap, R4 is too high, etc.

Comment: You remind me of Passerby.

Comment: @HarrySvensson. It that a good or bad thing...

Comment: Good thing. [He](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/17178/passerby)'s a reputable person.

Comment: I have made the changes you suggested and although the voltage spikes have disappeared I now have a waveform which diminishes from 12V down to about 2V.

Comment: I have made the changes suggested and the voltage spikes have disappeared. However now the voltage starts at 12V and diminished down to about 2V. Any further suggestions appreciated. Refer original post.

Comment: Is that the output or the MOSFET output? Can you show an image? By the way, why have R1? Maybe 10 ohms at most, but you could put a 1/4 amp fuse here as well. R1 as 100 ohms limits your MOSFET drive voltage, in terms of turning the MOSFET OFF. The NE555 is not a good choice because its output cannot go higher than V1 -1.2 volts. Put a 2.2K resistor from MOSFET gate to V1 supply to make sure the MOSFET will turn OFF on positive pulses from the 555.

Comment: It is very late here. I go to bed now. Good luck.